# Swiftui Firestore SnapshotListener on Single Document error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am getting :

> "Cannot assign to property: function call returns immutable value" error in this part:
> "self.vm2.filteredPosts(searchingText2)[index].liked = doc.liked".

Any idea how I can solve it? My goal is to add a snapshot listener when a user clicks on a post after searching but I haven't been able to make it work.

```
LazyVGrid(columns: items, spacing: 2, content: {
    ForEach(searchingText.isEmpty ? [] : viewModel.filteredPosts(searchingText)) { post in
        NavigationLink(
            destination:
                Postview(viewModel2: PostViewModel(post: post))
                .onAppear{
                currentListener =
                Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").document(post.postId).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, err in
                    guard let index = self.viewModel.filteredPosts(searchingText).firstIndex(where: { $0.id == post.id }) else { return }
                    if let doc = try? snapshot?.data(as: Post.self) {
                            self.viewModel.filteredPosts(searchingText)[index].liked = doc.liked
                    }
                }
            } ,label: {
               Text("See likes")
        })
    }
})
```

```
func filteredPosts(_ query: String) -> [Post] {
        let lowercasedQuery2 = query.lowercased()
        return posts.filter({
            $0.caption.lowercased().contains(lowercasedQuery2) 
        })
    }
```